# Set datefirst in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, powerbi

I'm working on a SQLquery, but I have some problems with `set datefirst`.

Since I'm working in a directquery from PowerBI, I am not able to put `SET DATEFIRST 1` in front of my query.

I need the all the data from 1 table, from last week. So for instance:
Now it's thursday, I need all the information from last week (Monday until sunday).

I have this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM myDB
WHERE CreatedDateTime >= DATEADD(day, -(DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) + 6), CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())) 
    AND CreatedDateTime <  DATEADD(day, 1 - DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()), CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))
    AND Minutes is not null
    AND Minutes > 0
    AND TicketNumber like 'CH%'
    AND User like 'itsn%' 
    AND TicketNumber is not null
```

How can I set the first day of the week to monday within the select?

Comment: I found this codepart on Stack:


declare @MyDate datetime = getdate()
                   select CASE WHEN DATEPART(DW,@MyDate) = 1   
                            THEN 7 
                          WHEN DATEPART(DW,@MyDate) <= 7 
                            THEN DATEPART(DW,@MyDate) - 1                            
                     END


But can't find a way the get it in my own code

Comment: Looks more like SQL Server than MySQL. Please tag correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually have the right code in your comment (the `CASE` statement).

To get it into your existing code, just replace your current `DATEPART` function with the `CASE` statement. The final query will look something like this.

```
SELECT *
FROM myDB
WHERE CreatedDateTime >= DATEADD(day, -(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DW, GETDATE()) = 1 THEN 7 ELSE DATEPART(DW, GETDATE()) - 1 END + 6), CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())) 
    AND CreatedDateTime <  DATEADD(day, 1 - CASE WHEN DATEPART(DW, GETDATE()) = 1 THEN 7 ELSE DATEPART(DW, GETDATE()) - 1 END, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))
    AND Minutes is not null
    AND Minutes > 0
    AND TicketNumber like 'CH%'
    AND User like 'itsn%' 
    AND TicketNumber is not null
```

Just as an illustration, here is a quick check of the query. When it is the 22nd (a Sunday), the range is the 9th through the 16th. When the date goes to the 23rd (a Monday), the range moves up to the 16th through the 23rd.

[image: Check]

Comment: Wauw @joe, you are great. This works perfect. Thank you very much